# Searching for a non-neutral term that means "Enjoys risk" which is not Daredevil or Gambler

Tags: meaning, connotation, semantics

Searching for a term that means someone who 'enjoys taking risks,' rather than 'someone who is not averse to taking risk' or 'someone who overcomes their aversion to risk.' "Undaunted" is neutral in response to fear; it isn't the same as "Enjoying dangerous situations." The closest words I can find are "Daredevil" and "Gambler." Semantically, Daredevil has too many connotations tying it to physical risk rather than all types of risk, and Gambler can be easily misunderstood as someone who frequents casinos. I'm willing to accept that within the constraints as I have defined them, there may be no word, but I thought I'd ask here just in case someone can think of one.

Comment: *Adrenaline junky* is another term, though it may also have too much of an implication of physical risk. Non-physical dangers can provoke the same physiological responses within the body though.

Comment: This is unclear. You're not specifying what kinds of risks you do want to take. What is the situation you're trying to capture?

Comment: In economics, the contrast to *risk-averse* is *risk-seeking*

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for **"adventurous"**?

> **"adventurous"** (adj.)
>
> - "Willing to take risks or to try out new methods, ideas, or experiences."
>     Origin: Middle English from Old French aventureus, from aventure.         [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/adventurous)
> - "Ready to take risks or to deal with new or unexpected problems.  Adventurous implies a willingness to accept risks but not necessarily imprudence." [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adventurous)
>
> e.g.
>
> Adventurous youngsters went on a hike through the forest. [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adventurous)
>
> He is an adventurous cook who is always trying new recipes.  [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adventurous)

Answer (score 1):

Somebody who enjoys taking risks because of the feeling it brings is, in general, a **sensation-seeker** or, more colloquially, an **adrenaline junkie**.

---

From the definition of [*adrenaline junkie*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/adrenaline_junkie) at Lexico (Oxford Dictionaries):

> A person with a compulsive desire for excitement and adventure.
>
> *‘a bit of an adrenaline junkie, he appears to have no regard for his own safety’*
> *‘All his experiences disarming and disposing of bombs made him an adrenaline junkie.’*
> *‘An adrenaline junkie from an early age, Aaron was into every extreme sport you can imagine.’*

---

From ["Can You Be Addicted to Adrenaline?"](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/science-choice/201508/can-you-be-addicted-adrenaline) by Shahram Heshmat at Psychology Today:

> Adrenaline is a substance released in the body when a person feels a strong emotion, such as excitement, fear, or anger. The adrenaline rush usually occurs when the body senses danger, the “fight or flight” moment.
>
> Some people, known as sensation-seekers, are adrenaline junkies. Psychologist Marvin Zuckerman defines sensation-seeking behavior as the pursuit of novel and intense experiences without regard for physical, social, legal, or financial risk. Sensation-seeking is a general personality trait. And like any personality trait, it is more than 50 percent determined by heredity.

---

From ["Why gamblers get high even when they lose"](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20160721-the-buzz-that-keeps-people-gambling) by Chris Baraniuk at BBC Future:

> The first thing to note is that people don’t just gamble for the prospect of winning. Mark Griffiths, a psychologist at Nottingham Trent University who specialises in behavioural addictions points out that gamblers list a wide range of motivations for their habit.
>
> In a survey of 5,500 gamblers, the prospect of the chance to “win big money” was the strongest factor. But it was followed closely by “because it’s fun” and “because it’s exciting”.
>
> "Even when you’re losing while you’re gambling, your body is still producing adrenalin and endorphins," he says.

Answer (score 0):

an **audacious** person  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/audacious)
adj.

> 1. Fearlessly, often recklessly daring; bold.
> 2. Unrestrained by convention or propriety; brazen or insolent: audacious rudeness.
> 3. Spirited and original:

Audacious comes from Latin audacia: daring, boldness and courage. Challenging conventions and doing things that most people don't do, that is an **audacious** individual.